# I am getting Error while Cross-compiling my application program for LS1043

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling, arm64

I am using LS1043 board, I want to generate rootfs for my application.   I am trying to compile my application program.

While cross-compiling my application I am getting errors. I think I have some problem in my `Makefile`.
I try to cross compile an application to be run on arm target (my host is `x86 ubuntu 20.04`). when i run `make`, i obtain this error:

Herewith I am attaching my error screenshot and `Makefile`.

```
LD=aarch64-fsl-linux-ld
CC=aarch64-fsl-linux-gcc  

OBJS2=main.o terminalMode.o trap.o filedownload_spidev.o 
TARGETS=main 

CFLAGS=-I/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/include --sysroot=/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/ -I/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/net-snmp/5.9.3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/include `/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/net-snmp/usr/bin/crossscripts/net-snmp-config --cflags `-m64  -lrt   -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mabi=lp64 -linux --sysroot=/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots/ls1043ardb -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -pthread

BUILDLIBS=-L/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots/ls1043ardb/lib `/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/net-snmp/usr/bin/crossscripts/net-snmp-config  --libs` -L/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/lib -L /opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/lib 

BUILDAGENTLIBS=-L/home/icomm//distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/net-snmp/5.9.3-r0/image/usr/lib `/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/net-snmp/5.9.3-r0/image/usr/bin/net-snmp-config --agent-libs` 

DLFLAGS=--disable-debugging

all: $(TARGETS)

main: $(OBJS2)
    $(CC)  -o main $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS2) $(BUILDLIBS) $(BUILDAGENTLIBS)
clean:
    rm $(OBJS2) $(TARGETS)
```

**error**

```
aarch64-fsl-linux-gcc    -o main -I /opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/include --sysroot=/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/ -I/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/net-snmp/5.9.3-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/include `/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/net-snmp/usr/bin/crossscripts/net-snmp-config --cflags `-m32  -lrt   -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mabi=lp64 -linux --sysroot=/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots/ls1043ardb  main.o terminalMode.o trap.o filedownload_spidev.o  -L /home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots/ls1043ardb/ `/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/net-snmp/usr/bin/crossscripts/net-snmp-config  --libs`  -L /opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fsl-linux/usr/lib/  -L/home/icomm//distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/net-snmp/5.9.3-r0/image/usr/lib `/home/icomm/distro/build_ls1043ardb/tmp/work/aarch64-fsl-linux/net-snmp/5.9.3-r0/image/usr/bin/net-snmp-config --agent-libs` 
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -linux
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lpci
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find /lib/libc.so.6
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
/opt/fsl-qoriq/3.1/sysroots/x86_64-fslsdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-fsl-linux/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/9.3.0/real-ld: cannot find /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:32: main] Error 1
```

I think I have to do changes in `Makefile`, what are the hanges needed, I don't know. I need help

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please copy-paste the logs you have on console instead of sending an image. They are easier to read.